# Setting global environment variables via /etc/launchd.conf on Mac OS X 10.6 does not work

Tags: macos, global-variables, environment-variables, launchd

I am trying to set some global environment variables on Mac OS X 10.6 so that they are set for applications as well as shell sessions.

So far I have tried the following methods:

- [Editing /etc/launchd.conf](http://www.digitaledgesw.com/node/31)
- Creating ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist and putting them in there
- Editing /etc/profile

None of these work! The one I found most surprising was /etc/launchd.conf as it seems to work fine for everyone else who has tried it. Is there any logical reason why it is not working for me?

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [http://apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Good point, if a moderator thinks that it is more appropriate for this question to be on there, please can they move it. Bearing in mind though, that there are much less users on there so it might take a lot longer to get answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a similar problem to what I was having installing Derby. The way I solved it was by opening TextEdit. Select File > Open at this point press Shift + Command + . , this will allow you to view all the documents. Head to the user directory and search for a file called ".profile" . Open it and add the export VARIABLE= Value line for example:

export DERBY_HOME=/opt/local/share/java/derby/

Save the document and restart your terminal to see if the changes went into affect.